# Calculate Object Size for Different Screens

Tags: appcelerator, image-resizing, aspect-ratio, aspect

I'm writing an app in Appcelerator that will be running different mobile screens. So, there will be many screen sizes and ratios.

Let me simply ask like this; I have an image object and I want it to protect its ratio on different screens.

How can I calculate the width & height of this object for different screens?

Object Sizes in 1920 X 1080 screen is 885 X 109.

(For example) What should be the sizes of 812 X 375(iPhone X size) screen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Alloy.Globals.WIDTH = (OS_ANDROID) ? Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth / Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor : Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;
Alloy.Globals.HEIGHT = (OS_ANDROID) ? Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight / Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor : Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight;
```

to get the proper device size.

But I'm not sure if I understand the question. You don't need to do anything special about the aspect ration of your image on different devices. You can use `Ti.UI.SIZE` on `width` or `height` and a fixed value on the other property to keep the aspect ratio. E.g. if you image should always be 300dp width set the height to `Ti.UI.SIZE`. 
If you want to adjust the image width to the device screen width but keep a left/right margin you can use

```
image.width = Ti.UI.FILL;
image.left = 10;
image.right = 10;
imahe.height = Ti.UI.SIZE;
```

For other calculations you can use the `Alloy.Globals.WIDTH` or `Alloy.Globals.WIDTH` from above (put it into alloy.js) and multiply it by the image ratio to get the other side.

Comment: Why are you computing the width and height differently on ios and android?  If your app is set to use dp as the default unit, you should be able to use  Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth|Height on both platforms.

I believe that it has been standard to include 

`<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dip</property>`

in `tiapp.xml` for quite some time now.

Comment: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth -> 1080,
Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth/Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor -> 360 (with default dip). Most of the time I need the 2nd value so I set that in my globals

Comment: Sorry -- you're right.  I've used a library around those functions for so long (4 years +) that I forgot that you have to divide the platformWidth by the logicalDensityFactor.  My library just handles that automatically.

Comment: logicalDensityFactor for iPhone X equal 3. But I get correct values by dividing 2. Sometimes Appcelerator is really driving me crazy! :)